# Accessing windows servers

Tags: networking, kde, samba

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 with kde desktop.  I want to access some files on windows machines on the home network.  I have installed Samba.  I have followed configuration instructions. When I go to the default file manager - Dolphin, there is no area in the left hand pane for "connecting to server" to allow me to proceed.  What should I do next?
I can connect from the windows machines to the shared folder on Ubuntu but not vice versa. I can ping the servers on the home network from Ubuntu.  I have enabled sharing on the windows servers.  When this Ubuntu machine was W11 I could access the files on those machines.  Guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> When I go to the default file manager - Dolphin, there is no area in
> the left hand pane for "connecting to server" to allow me to proceed.

In Dolphin on the left hand pane select "Network". At the top of Dolphin select "Add Network Folder":

[image]

For this to work properly with SMB you need to go to Menu > Settings > System Settings > Network > Settings > Windows Shares:

For user name and password use anything - or use **guest** for user name and **xxx** for password. This will allow the system to prompt you for credentials if credentials are needed.

Comment: I have tried to do as you have suggested but despite using the wizard I am still unable to connect with the server even when they are wired together on the home network. Currently I feel that I am asking the wrong question but would appreciate some advice about where to turn to answer this, written in simple language.

Comment: KDE makes things far more complicated than it needs to be. Please see my edit above.